# Giving error erratically : SQLServer Linked Server through MySQL Connector ODBC 8.0.28

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, linked-server

I have a linked server on SQLServer, pointing to a MySQL server, through MySQL Connector ODBC driver

There is a job, that run several steps, each one retrieving new rows from different tables. ( Although one step fails, the job is programmed to continue with rest of the steps )

Unexpectedly, erratically, one of the steps fails giving **error 7357 Can't access object**. After that, the rest of the steps are fired as it was programmed, but finish **error 7320 Can't execute query**

Sometimes, really few times, the rest of the steps gives no error

I'm trying to find if the error is in the driver, or in the MySQL

I don't discard anything. The MySQL DB is a live replica of the production DB. I don't know if the replication could introduce some pitfall

--
SQLServer 2019
MySQL 8.0.17
MySQL Connector ODBC driver 8.0.28

Comment: Is there code on the remote MySQL system that's dropping and recreating permissions on the target tables?

Comment: Also Connector/ODBC 8.0.28 was released in Nov-2021, have you considered upgrading to the current Connector/ODBC 8.0.32 to see if there are related bug fixes?

Comment: As far as we are given to know, it's an online replica of the production server. *I think* the same commands issued in production, are issued in the replica, because the tables on the replica has AUTO_INCREMENT ids. The owner doesn't detail us too much.. I don't think there is a permissions problem. Instead, I suspect it could there be some process/job that is droppring connections. We can get PROCESSLIST only for our user. Owner only recognizes that the replication experiences "some delays, sometimes".  I'll ask if we can upgrade the driver, as you mentioned. I'll be writing soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I finally changed some options in the MySQL ODBC Connector, and it worked

- Allow big result sets
- Enable compression
- Do not cache
- Use Read Only cursors (combined with the previous)

Long running queries introduced lag on the replication. At some point something crashed. I really don't know the details. But this settings worked

Another setting I tried, was: PREFETCH -> 10000 rows

Please, be careful. With this setting, the table I read (a table with a PK, unique key)
**returned duplicated rows** (so duplicated keys) with a simply : select * from "theTable"

very weird...

( Remember my scenario, it's an online replicated server
and tables get several inserts a second
My task is to take data from that replica, to feed a data warehouse )